Flutter android build error: android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS [MissingPermission] notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
I am building a Flutter app for Android that uses Geolocator, and encountered the following error while running './gradlew clean build':
int found 1 errors, 6 warnings. First failure:  /home/daksh/.pub-cache/
hosted/pub.dev/geolocator_android-4.6.0/android/src/main/java/com/
baseflow/geolocator/location/BackgroundNotification.java:100: Error: 
Missing permissions required by NotificationManagerCompat.notify: 
android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS [MissingPermission]             
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build()); 

pubspec.yaml:
name: frontend
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.0.0

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  geolocator: ^12.0.0
  http: ^0.13.6
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
#  workmanager: ^0.5.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

Project-level build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

App-level build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.test_app"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.test_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 19
        targetSdk = 34
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.frontend">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>

    <application
        android:label="frontend"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

<!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

Kotlin MainActivity.kt:
package com.example.test_app

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 123

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        requestNotificationPermission()
    }

    private fun requestNotificationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried all the solutions to this error that I could, but none worked. Using Android SDK Upside Down Cake and Flutter version 3.22.2.

Can you post code of BackgroundNotification.java class?
